# Safari extension to monitor web pages for changes?

Tags: safari-extensions

I am looking for a Safari extension similar to [Update Scanner](http://updatescanner.mozdev.org/en/index.html) (for Firefox) and [Page Monitor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pemhgklkefakciniebenbfclihhmmfcd) (for Chrome). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know any extension like this one, but I've used [Changes Meter](http://intuiware.com/apps/changes-meter) which works really fine. It's a small app in your menubar and gets the job done.

Comment: I had never thought of looking for a separate application rather than a web browser extension. Works just as well. Thanks!

Comment: Is this still available?  There's mention of it on the site, but there doesn't appear to be any way to download it (and I don't see it in the app store).

Comment: Changes Meter was never updated to 64-bit so it doesn't work in Catalina.

Answer (score 2):

[Changes Meter](http://intuiware.com/apps/changes-meter) is an app that just notify you about some change in web page. But it does not inform you about what has changed.

Comment: Can you please provide a link to the tool mentioned?

Comment: Changes Meter was never updated to 64-bit so it doesn't work in Catalina.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using https://urlooker.com, it has free plan, shows exact changes and supports JS-generated pages.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Answer (score 0):

I've found this old software that might do the trick [Safari Page Monitor](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/13573/safari-page-monitor)

Answer (score 0):

Using a browser extension for this means it will only notify you when your browser is online.

I use http://changemon.com which notifies me 24x7 and it's quite simple to use.

You don't even have to sign up on the site.